# Hourly limit exceeded for processing workflow time triggers salesforce

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I am facing an issue on "Hourly limit exceeded for processing workflow time triggers".I found a way to increase the org limit.But is there any way I can understand which workflows are causing this issue.Because on my knowledge there arent that much workflows.

Comment: Check in setup>monitor>Time-Based Workflow

Comment: @Amit What filters do I have to apply in the Time based Workflow to get all the pending automations.Can you elaborate.

Comment: To get all pending automation click on search  button without any criteria.

Comment: @Amit Thanks it worked.

Comment: Adding this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check pending workflow actions Check in

> Setup> Monitor> Time-Based Workflow

To search all pending action workflows click on search without entering any criteria.

For more information refer this salesforce documentation - [Monitor Pending Workflow Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workflow_queue.htm&type=5)